# Make global copy of local variables in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have extracted a username, password and another password with express like this:

```
var urlencodedParser = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var un = req.body.username;
    var pw1 = req.body.pwd1;
    var pw2 = req.body.pwd2;
});
```

I then want to do something with the new variables I have created. How can I use them outside of this function?

Comment: You can create a new function i.e. above your code and call this function inside your endpoint callback with variables as parameters. Then you can use variables.

Comment: In general, in a multi-request, multi-user server, you don't use the variables outside this request handler.  You either use them in the function, or you pass them as arguments and call to some other function from this function or you store them in some storage mechanism that accounts for which user they belong to (user session or database or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make them global or pass them to the next function

```
var un, pw1, pw2
var urlencodedParser = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    un = req.body.username;
    pw1 = req.body.pwd1;
    pw2 = req.body.pwd2;
});
```

Or passing them on:

```
var urlencodedParser = bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    doSomething(req.body.username, req.body.pw1, req.body.pw2);
});

function doSomething(un, pw1, pw2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This first option is a bad suggestion as it's almost never the right choice in a multi-user server process and certainly not something you should guide a novice developer towards because they are very likely to use that to code something that doesn't work for mult-users.  The second option makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you! Passing them on worked perfectly, as well as shortening my code :)

Comment: Good luck! @jfriend00 I just added the globals since that was the OP's question. Agreed that the function is the better solution.

Comment: I'm just worried that if the OP implemented the globals, they will be in for a nasty concurrency surprise sometime in the future.  It would be better not to even show them that option since it's never the right way to program a server.